# Finding coefficients of a quadratic with roots having certain intervals

Tags: calculus, inequality, quadratics

> If the roots of the quadratic equation $$(4p−p^2  −5)x^2  −(2p−1)x+3p=0$$ lie on either side of unity, then the number of integral values of $p$ is?

Okay so I'm having a hard time what the question means by both sides of unity. Does it mean one root is on $ x>1 $ and other in $ x<1$? After that, how do I adjust the coefficent so that one root is greater tha one?

Comment: That is how I would interpret it.

Comment: I think my answer is better.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If the leading coefficient is positive, then the condition $f(1)\lt 0$ suffices. If it is negative, then we want $f(1)\gt 0$. These conditions can be condensed into $$(4p-p^2-5) f(1)\lt 0 $$ Can you finish?

Comment: I don't understand, why is it this condition?

Comment: For the first case, the parabola faces upwards. If we ensure $f(1)$ is below the $x$ axis, then by continuity of the graph, the two roots *must* lie on either side $1$. You might like to test this with the help of a diagram. Similarly for the other case.

Answer (score 1):

First notice that leading coefficient $a=-(p^2-4p+4+1) = -(p-2)^2-1$ is negative.

If the roots of quadratic function $$f(x)=(4p−p^2  −5)x^2  −(2p−1)x+3p$$ are $x_1$ and $x_2$ (say $x_1>x_2$) then we have $$x_2<1<x_1\implies 1-x_2>0 \;\;{\rm and}\;\; 1-x_1<0$$

So if we write write $f$ in factor form:$$f(x)=a(x-x_1)(x-x_2)$$
then we see that $$f(1) = a(1-x_1)(1-x_2)>0$$

So you need to solve $f(1)=-(p-4)(p-1)>0$ ...

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: what does the triangle symbol mean? after you wrote  " are $ x_1 $ and $ x_2$ " you put upside down triangle in next line

Comment: It means "and".